# Combinatorics terminology for list of options

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, terminology

I am currently working with lists of options, where the options are numbered from $1$ to $n_k$ and are ordered increasingly, where $k$ is the number of lists.

> **Question 1:** currently I am calling these simply *sequences*, do these have a more specific name?

From these list of options, I am generating $k$-tuples, where the elements of the tuples are the options of the lists, in the order the lists have been defined so they have the same index, like this:
$S_1 = (1, 2, 3)$
$S_2 = (1, 2)$
$S_3 = (1, 2, 3, 4)$
All $k$-tuples:
$(1, 1, 1)$
$(1, 1, 2)$
$(1, 1, 3)$
$(1, 1, 4)$
$(1, 2, 1)$
$(1, 2, 2)$
$(1, 2, 3)$
$(1, 2, 4)$
$(2, 1, 1)$
$(2, 1, 2)$
$(2, 1, 3)$
$(2, 1, 4)$
$(2, 2, 1)$
$(2, 2, 2)$
$(2, 2, 3)$
$(2, 2, 4)$
$(3, 1, 1)$
$(3, 1, 2)$
$(3, 1, 3)$
$(3, 1, 4)$
$(3, 2, 1)$
$(3, 2, 2)$
$(3, 2, 3)$
$(3, 2, 4)$
The order of the tuples doesn't matter, so the number of $k$-tuples become $n_1n_2...n_k$, in the example it is $3×2×4$.

> **Question 2:** currently I am calling this combinatorial operation simply *all possibilities*, does this have a specific name?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your "sequences"? Can you specify an example? It sounds like a direct product as well

Comment: @LegNaiB The examples are $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$. Should they be ordered sets instead of sequences?

Comment: All $k$-tuples you listed are just the ordered direct product, or what exactly are you asking for? I don't see the difference between question 1 and question 2

Comment: Q1 asks for the name of the object, Q2 asks for the name of the operation.

Comment: Ah okay, so the name should be direct product or not? The operation is then "taking the direct product", at least I would suggest that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the unordered list it's simply the direct (Cartesian) product of those sets:
$S_1\times S_2\times S_3$

The operation is "taking the Cartesian product" and the elements are tuples from the Cartesian product.

Comment: Or I could call the operation Cartesian product, and call everything a tuple. If no-one says otherwise, I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Yeah "taking" the Cartesian product is the operation and the object itself are tuples = elements of a Cartesian product